# creating XSD schema files for GAC dll

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

How can I use XSD.exe to create an XML schema for the `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Database` object?

Answer (score 2):

You can still access a gacced dll via the cmdline (in `%windir%\assembly\GAC_MSIL`):

```
C:\WINNT\assembly\GAC_MSIL>dir
 Volume in drive C is Omni3
 Volume Serial Number is 5CDE-38BA

 Directory of C:\WINNT\assembly\GAC_MSIL

29/01/2010  15:20              .
29/01/2010  15:20              ..
07/08/2009  15:54              Accessibility
07/08/2009  15:54              AspNetMMCExt
07/08/2009  08:39              CppCodeProvider
07/08/2009  08:45              CRVsPackageLib
07/08/2009  08:45              CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Design
```

etc...